# How to solve 'Cannot find a valid font for the family' error when adding text using ffmpeg-kit-react-native?

Tags: react-native

How to fix "Cannot find a valid font for the family Sans' while adding text on video using ffmpeg-kit-react-native

> LOG  Press [q] to stop, [?] for help 
> LOG  [Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0xb400007bb0842900] Cannot find a valid font for the family 1 
> LOG  [AVFilterGraph @ 0xb400007bb085c100] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' 
> LOG  [AVFilterGraph @ 0xb400007bb085c100]  with args 'font=1:text=my name is doraemon:fontcolor=red:fontsize=30:x=(640):y=(360)' 
> LOG  [AVFilterGraph @ 0xb400007bb085c100] 
> LOG  Error reinitializing filters! 
> LOG  Failed to inject frame into filter network: No such file or directory 
> LOG  Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0 
> LOG  Conversion failed! 
> LOG  Encode failed. Please check log for the details.

Comment: `this is my command line " -i ${uri} -vf "drawtext=font='./assets/fonts/arial.ttf':text=${text}:fontcolor=${color}:fontsize=${size}:x=(${x}):y=(${y})" -c:a copy  ${outputImagePath}"